# Какая коллекция хранит уникальные значения, сохраняет последовательность добавления?

Tags: java, коллекции

Скажите, какая есть коллекция (Collection) для строковых элементов (String), где строки не повторяются, но можно их вывести в том порядке, в каком они были добавлены?

Comment: Норм вопрос, не надо минусить. Он должен отлично индексироваться посиковиками и сим нести добро и причинять пользу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно смотреть в сторону `LinkedHashSet` видимо.

---

```
HashSet<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
mySet.add("Привет");
mySet.add("Абажур");
mySet.add("Трактор");
mySet.add("Ягуар");
mySet.add("Абажур");


// output
Iterator<String> iterator = mySet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}

Привет
Абажур
Трактор
Ягуар
```